# how to correctly wait for execve to finish?

Tags: c, linux, shell

A C source code (compiled and running Linux Centos 6.3) has the line:

```
execve(cmd, argv, envp);
```

`execve` does not return, but I want to modify the code to know when it is finished.  So I do this:

```
if (child = fork()) {
    waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
    /*now I know execve is finished*/
    exit(0);
}

execve(cmd, argv, envp);
```

When I do this, the resulting program works 99% of the time, but very rarely it exhibits strange errors.

Is anything wrong with the above??  I expect the above code to run precisely (except a little slower) as before.  Am I correct?

If you want to know the background, the modified code is `dash`.  The `execve` call is used to run a simple command, after `dash` has figured out the string to run.  When I modify precisely as above (without even running anything after waiting) and recompile and run programs under the modified dash, most of the time they run fine.  However, a recompilation of one particular kernel module called "biosutility" gives me this error

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfentry"
```

Comment: It's not clear why you have come to the conclusion that the `waitpid` is the cause of the error you are seeing. The connection may be obvious but I'm not seeing it. Since the error only occurs very occasionally how do you know that it is not an existing bug independent of `waitpid`? FWIW, the `waitpid` snippet looks fine to me except for the fact that `waitpid` is called even if `fork` fails (but that is unlikely to be a factor in the current question).

Comment: "*but very rarely it exhibits strange errors.*" What are these strange errors? Is it that `cc1` error you posted?

Comment: @Cornstalks yes that is the error

Comment: @kaylum well, if I don't change the code as above, everything works fine, including recompilation of that kernel module.  It has to work fine, because that is the only modification of `dash` that I do and `dash` is a known, well debugged program.So it is `fork` or `waitpid` that is causing the problem or both.

Comment: Does the program do anything between the waitpid and the exit?
(Note that fork() returns -1 if it fails which would cause it to go through the waitpid() statement, though I see nothing in your snippet which would cause a problem even in this case.)

Comment: @darklion no I am telling you, does not, that's the point, I eliminated all the extra code, leaving only `fork` and `waitpid` and the error remains

Comment: The argument `unrecognized command line option "-mfentry"` suggests you have `"-mfentry"` as part of `argv` and it is not recognized by the program or script you pass as `cmd`. It also implies that you are passing `cc1` as `cmd`. Are you also passing `cc1` as `argv[0]` as per the convention?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes I know...  but so what, that's why it is a "strange" error, it should not happen.  The arguments to that program, cc1, are the same regardless of the shell, if I recompile the dash shell as above, it should not change anything

Comment: Are there any patches not applied or missing when you recompile that could account for the shell no longer accepting that option? And both `argv` and `envp` are terminated by a `NULL` as the last element of each?? Only other thing I could think of that might cause `execve` to walk off the end of either `argv` or `envp` and pick up some stray option.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin David I am not sure if you are understanding the question, or maybe I have not explained.  I don't have anything to do with cc1.  I am modifying `dash` as above and running programs under the modified shell.  They run fine most of the time, which means, the shell is modified correctly, more or less.  I can recompile simple kernel modules under the modified shell, no problem.  But a particular kernel module "biosutility" does not recompile, it exits with the error as above.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin again, the code without the above modification, is perfectly fine, it is the `dash` source code, unmodified, so it has to have the correctly setup call to `execve`, there cannot possibly be a problem with unterminated args or anything like that.

Comment: Lightbulb on. OK, that makes sense. I was just looking at it from the `execve` use standpoint. What could cause it to behave differently. The only other thing I can think of is if in your recompile you changed the `#!` interpreter name somehow, and `cmd` was a script -- that could cause problems as well. Not knowing how you modify dash I'm all out of ammo. If all works prior to recompile and not after recompile, it is almost like something gets left out or altered in the dash rebuild. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you for trying to help...  no there are no other modifications of anything, only the above lines are added.  No other changes.

Comment: Maybe it is the `fork` rather than the `waitpid` that is the cause of the problem. With the change, the child process is the one that does the `execve` and not the parent process which would have been the case without the change. That can subtly change things. For example, any signals that are sent to the parent process will now no longer be handled correctly by the actual `execve` application. But not sure how that would translate to the symptoms you are seeing. So just a line of thought.

Comment: Forking an extra process and then hanging in a wait loop means that a bunch of file descriptors were duplicated and remain open, although they're not going to be used. That can have non-local consequences. There are some other details, like terminal ownership and signal handling. And of course, there is the issue that the pid of the process which is about to be exec'd will be different, so if it has already been stored somewhere for later use, that will be incorrect, too.

Comment: @kaylum  OK that's great, thank you.  Do you know then, how to correctly find out when the execve has finished

Comment: @rici  OK great insight, thank you, I don't like forking either... but then, how else can I know that execve has finished...??

Comment: @kaylum - `fork` to blame - perhaps...  if I don't wait, just call `fork` and exit the parent, then,...  again everything works 99% of the time, except that particular kernel module compilation that is giving error above, now fails altogether, without emitting any error.

Comment: Dash must already have a mechanism, since it doesn't leave zombies lying around. I don't know anything about dash internals, though, so i wouldn't even know where to look.

Comment: Can't really tell you how to do it in the dash context. Because the code you have is largely correct for waiting for child process to exit but perhaps needs to be placed in a different part of the dash code.

Comment: @kaylum I am not trying to get you to do my work for me...  I just wanted to know if what I am doing is theoretically correct...  that is the only place in `dash` code that does the `execve` - there is nowhere else to put it.  I am trying to do the same modification now to `bash` to see if the same behaviour happens.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Wasn't implying that you are trying to get me to do your work. Just saying that the limits of my knowledge have been reached.

Comment: @kaylum thank you I appreciate greatly.  Yes the same modification to `bash` produces the same exact problem.  So this has nothing to do with `dash` .  I am just not understanding some deeper consequence of what I am doing.  Darn.  I wish I knew where to start looking....  thank you again.

Comment: Ok, following up on my observation that you are confusing dash's memory of pids, and remembering that dash already has a mechanism to track child processes. Dash thinks it has started process pidx and it will want to know its status code at exit. But your fork means that you are process pidx and the child is now pidy. The child finishes, you reap and ignore its status code, and do a successful return. Result: bash thinks the child succeeded. Maybe it failed and the script wants to do something only on success...

Comment: ... The bottom line is that dash already tracks child lifetimes, but you haven't hooked into its existing mechanism. You should do that, because adding a different mechanism is not going to be easy. Tbh, I suspect an XY problem here.

Comment: @rici yes I think you are right on point, if you make it into the answer I will accept it.  I made a "mini-shell" which just does `execve` on whatever is passed to it...  Lo and behold, it does not suffer from the problem above.  So...  yes I agree with you, I have to understand what it is in the 'real' shell that makes my modification fail.

Comment: Haven't read through all of these comments, but are you running on some obscure platform which guarantees that fork() never fails?  It seems odd that you are not doing any error checking at all on the fork.

Comment: You have your last paragraph mentioning a compilation error, that should be a separate question and you should give the entire compilation command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility.

`dash` does, in fact, need to know when a child process terminates. It must reap the child (by `wait`ing it) to avoid filling the process table with zombies, and anyway it cares about the exit status of the process.

Now, it knows what the PID of the process it started was, and it can use that when it does a `wait` to figure out which process terminated and therefore what to do with the exit status.

But you are doing an extra `fork`. So `dash` thinks it started some process with PID, say, 368. But you `fork` a new child, say PID 723. Then you `wait` for that child, but you ignore the status code. Finally, your process terminates successfully. So then `dash` notices that process 368 terminated successfully. Even if it didn't.

Now suppose `dash` was actually executing a script like

```
do_something && do_something_else
```

The programmer has specified that the shell definitely shouldn't `do_something_else` if `do_something` failed. Terrible things could happen. Or at least mysterious things. Yet, you have hidden that failure. So `dash` cheerfully fires up `do_something_else`. *Et voilà*

Well, it's just a theory. I have no idea, really, but it shows the sort of thing that can happen.

The bottom line is that `dash` has some mechanism which lets it know when child processes have finished, and if you want to hook into the exit handling of a child process, you'd be much better off figuring out how that mechanism works so that you can hook into it. Trying to add your own additional mechanism is almost certain to end in tears.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: except the question itself :)

Answer (score 5):

Read *carefully* documentation of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and of [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). Both `execve` & `fork` are tricky and **[fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) is difficult to understand**. I strongly suggest to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (freely available online, but you could buy the paper book) which has *several chapters* for these questions.

<sup>(Don't be afraid of spending a few days reading and understanding these system calls, they *are* tricky)</sup>

Some important points.

- ***every* [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) *can fail* and you should *always* handle its failure**, at least by showing some error message with [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) and immediately [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)-ing.
- the **[execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)** syscall *usually never returns*, since it **returns *only* on failure** (when successful, it does not return, since the calling program has been replaced so wiped out!) hence most calls to it (and similar [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions) are often like:

  ```
  if (execve(cmd, argv, envp)) { perror (cmd); exit(127); };
  /* else branch cannot be reached! */
  ```

  it is customary to use a weird exit code like 127 (usually unused, except like above) on `execve`  failure, and very often you could not do anything else.
  When used (almost always) with `fork` you'll often call `execve` in the *child* process.
- the **[fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscall returns *twice* on success** (once in parent process, once in child process). This is tricky to understand, read the references I gave. It returns *once only on failure*. So you **always keep the result of `fork`**, so typical code would be:

  ```
   pid_t pid = fork ();
   if (pid<0) { // fork has failed 
      perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   else if (pid==0) { // successful fork in the child process
     // very often you call execve in child, so you don't continue here.
     // example code:
     if (execve(cmd, argv, envp)) { perror (cmd); exit(127); };
     // not reached! 
  };
  // here pid is positive, we are in the parent and fork succeeded....
  /// do something sensible, at some point you need to call waitpid and use pid
  ```

Suggestion: use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on some programs, perhaps try `strace -f bash -c 'date; pwd'` and study the output. It mentions many [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)....

Your sample code might (sometimes) work by just adding some `else` like

```
// better code, but still wrong because of unhandled failures....
if ((child = fork())>0) { 
  waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
  /*now I know execve is finished*/
  exit(0);
}
/// missing handling of `fork`  failure!
else if (!child) {
   execve(cmd, argv, envp);
   /// missing handling of `execve` failure
}
```

but that code is still incorrect because failures are not handled.

Answer (score 1):

Following Rici's excellent comments and answer, I found the root cause of the problem.

The original code exits with whatever `cmd` exited. I changed that to exit with 0 always.  That is why the code behaves differently.

The following fix does not exhibit the error:

```
int status;

if (child = fork()) {
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        /*now we know execve is finished*/
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            exit(WEXITSTATUS(status));
        exit(1);
    }

execve(cmd, argv, envp);
```

Comment: The `waitpid()` call will fail with `ECHILD` since `parent` is not a direct child of the current process. If you want to go this way, you will have to use some (non-portable and usually complicated) mechanism to wait for a process to terminate which is not a child.

Comment: @jilles yes indeed, that was a bad idea, it "worked" at first :)

Comment: @jilles I fixed the problem and edited the answer, thank you jilles!

Answer (score -1):

for this question: "is anything wrong with the above??"

and regarding this code:

```
if (child = fork()) {
    waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
    /*now I know execve is finished*/
    exit(0);
}

execve(cmd, argv, envp);
```

1. the `fork()` function has three kinds of returned value:

   - `-1` means an error occurred
   - `=0` means `fork()` was successful and the child process is running
   - `>0` means `fork()` was successful and the parent process is running
2. the call to `execvp()` needs to be followed

(for the rare case of the call failing) with

```
 perror( "execvp failed" );
 exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
```

3. the call to `fork()` returns a `pid_t`.

After the call, the code needs to be similar to: (using `child` as the pid variable)

```
if( 0 > child )
{
    perror( "fork failed");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

else if( 0 == child )
{ // then child process
    execve(cmd, argv, envp);
    perror( "execvp failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

//else
//{ // else parent process
waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
```

for your second question, about the error message:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfentry"
```

the word: `unrecognized` is mis-spelled, so this is not the actual error message.

This error message is not related to your question about the changes you made to `dash`.

However, the `dash` does not directly invoke any compile operations, so I suspect the questions are totally unrelated.

Suggest looking at the makefile for the `biosutility` utility for why there is a invalid parameter being passed to `cc1`.

Comment: you provide good coding practices, but...  they are not applicable in an SSCCE.  You don't answer the question.

Comment: @MarkGaleck, just what is a SSCCE?   It seemed to me the question was along the line of: `my code does not consistently work, why not?`  It does not consistently work because the call to `fork()` and its' returned value is not being correctly handled and the call to `execve()` is not properly handled.  I presented a way to fix that problem and to properly handle the returned value from `fork()` and the call to `execve()`.  The OP did not provide enough info to proceed beyond that info.

Comment: @MarkGaleck,   The OP did not provide a complete code example, nor just what the displayed problems (that occur occasionally) nor what is in argv[] on failure.  I could just vote to close because the question was about a runtime problem because the OP did not provide the required info. instead I tried to be helpful.

Comment: @MarkGaleck, of course, the OP did not mention if the compile works successfully with the original `dash` code (and did not post the unmodified code)  So, given the scant info, my only choice was to assume that the modified code was the root of the problem.

Comment: If you want to know what SSCCE is, google it, it's easy.  Questions and answers on this website should be presented with SSCCE. That's not my own opinion, everybody knows that.  SSCCE does not include error handling, unless it is relevant.  In this case, it is not.  If I follow your answer as to error handling, nothing changes.  The problem has nothing to do with error handling of execve or fork.

Comment: I did in fact provide "complete" code, that is what SSCCE does.  I am sorry, in my opinion, you don't understand how to pose questions correctly, and how to use SSCCE.  Posting the "whole" code from beginning to end, is in fact the wrong thing to do.  Yes many posters do it - because I am afraid they are lazy.  One should always show research effort and post the minimal example relevant.  If you disagree with me, I don't want to argue, about things that are obvious, let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: @MarkGaleck,  in this case, the answer was about the proper usage of the `fork()` and the `execve()` function,  that includes the necessary error handling.  The OPs posted code will call `waitpid()` with a PID of -1 when the `fork()` fails.  That is definitely an error and needed to be addressed.  The posted code will always call `execve()`, even if the `fork()` fails.  That is an error and needed to be addressed.

Comment: @MarkGaleck,  Reading the 'help center' for stack overflow says for the OP to produce a MCVE,  not a SSCCE.  This is further discussed at: <http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283437/mcve-vs-sscce-battle> and elsewhere.  And since the posted code does not work in all cases, it is not a SSCCE.  When the OP has a runtime problem, they are expected to post a short code that cleanly compiles and still shows the problem.  Then we can debug the code.