# A shell-like application in C on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

Ok. So I'm trying to write a shell like application to run in the Ubuntu terminal but I don't know where to start. I need to write a C program in a text editor, run the program in the existing terminal (`ioana@ioana-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ gcc OS.c -o OS.c` and than `./OS`).

My C program should reset the terminal and let me remake and/or somehow import the basic function from the original shall(I should write an exit function that will close the terminal, but it should not be mistaken with the exit from the original shall of the terminal; make the buffer for key UP-DOWN history that won't be mistaken with the one already implemented). I read a bit about `ncurses` library and also installed it.

All I have so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ncurses.h"

int main()
{
     system("reset");
     return 0;
}
```

It's a perfect running code and it clears the screen but if I press UP or DOWN, the previous commends are displayed and if I type exit the terminal closes. I don't want any of these.
I'll be pretty grateful if someone can explain what I can do. I read about those subjects but didn't manage to find something that I can clearly understand.

Comment: This is the most basic program possible, and why to include *ncurses.h* if you don't use it?

Comment: Try using `history -c`. This command cleans up command history. Namely the file at `~/.bash_history file `

Comment: There are a number of basic shell implementations in C already on StackOverflow - just search. Your basic approach is to read/store the desired command from the user, and then pass that command to either `popen` or `fork` and call the likes of `execv` in a loop. Search and you will find them.

Comment: I know what you are saying, the problem is that I really don't know where to start. If you can give me a link to an example I would be grateful.

Comment: A shell with terminal handling is one of the more complex things you can do in UNIX system programming.  I recommend you to wait trying to implement this until you got very familiar with how the system works.

Comment: By the way, what you observe is not your program's effect. Your program terminates after executing `reset`, it's the shell you invoke the program from that does what you say.

Comment: Is it a homework or what?

Comment: The start of it. I think that if I can do this I'll manage to work out the rest....

Comment: Use of nucrses library is pointless in your program. `Ncurses` is a library to mange console output just more advanced than basic functions such as `printf` and `scanf` and etc.

Answer (score 2):

Several issues and hints:

- read first [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (a book, also freely available online) to learn more about how to use [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...). Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to discover what system calls are done by some programs (so try `strace date` then `strace -f bash -c 'date; pwd'`...). Read about [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).
- [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) & [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) are the basics of every shell; see my hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830310/841108). But they are difficult to understand. If you want to have [command pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), you'll also need [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html); for redirection, you'll also need [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)
- understand what [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) is. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and the references there.
- terminals are in fact ttys, demystified [here](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/). For historical reasons, they are complex. See [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)
- history and command line editing and auto-completion are well handled with the [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library; full screen console-like editing (à la `emacs` or `vi`) would need the [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library; but it is not the essential part of a shell.
- [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29) can be tricky. Read about [process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). See [getpgid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpgid.2.html) & [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html)
- all Linux shells are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so please study their source code. The [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) shell has few features (and some bugs!), but its source code is small and easy to read. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [zsh](http://zsh.org/), [fish](http://fishshell.com/) have more features so are more complex.
- The [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function is forking itself a `/bin/sh` shell, so using it in your own shell is somehow cheating.

PS. If you are new to all that, making a full-featured shell would take several months.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you!