# Global variables and their scope in C between files

Tags: c, scope, global-variables

I am writing an implementation of semaphores in Minix and am unsure about one thing.

If calling a function included from a header and that function is using a global array, is that array:

1. The same for all processes that call that function?
2. Different for each process that calls that function?
3. Different for each call of that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that the notion of [*process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) is mentioned in the C99 standard. Let's pretend your C implementation is on Linux, or at least a POSIX one.

Then, each process has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (which gets lazily duplicated by [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), is changed with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & `munmap` & [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) etc..., is replaced by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) ....) and the global variables are sitting in that address space.

Hence, your choice 2 is the correct one (on Linux at least, and probably on Minix because it is POSIX compliant and Unix-like...).

BTW, it would be the same with `static` arrays.

See also references and links given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830310/841108).

Comment: Thanks, that does seem logical. Any idea on how that would work when fork-ing or exec-ing? Would the forked process inherit the array?

Comment: @m_highlanderish: C does not know about porocesses. That already answers your question. Note that it is a part of the broader question "What is a process". You should read about that.